# How to insert new value into ordered hash after given element?

Tags: ruby, hash

I want to use ordered hash.

```
existing_hash = { key: value1, foo: value2 }

I want add { bar: value3 } after key 'key:'
expecting_hash = { key: value1, bar: value3, foo: value2 }
```

My code:

```
existing_hash[:bar] = value3
actual_hash =  { key: value1, foo: value2, bar: value3 }
```

Comment: Hash is unordered data structure (in general, though in ruby it happens to be ordered, but that's implementatin detail). You should rethink what you're doing. If you need ordering, use arrays.

Comment: You expect three methods `add`, `value`, and `after` to work together to get that result? What is `key:`? I don't think that is a valid Ruby construct. And most of all, where is your question?

Comment: Sorry, this mean "I want add { bar: value3 } after key key:". look like method is my mislead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Sergio is right about unordered nature of `Hash`, but technically it looks sorta interesting.

Could not refrain from find a solution :)

Here it is, though not really elegant:

```
# having this and need to insert 3 after 2
h = {1=>:one, 2=>:two, 4=>:four, 5=>:five}

after_key = 2
after_key_index = h.keys.index(after_key)
h1,h2 = h.partition {|k,v| h.keys.index(k) <= after_key_index }.map {|a| Hash[a]}

p h1.merge(3 => :three).merge(h2)
# => {1=>:one, 2=>:two, 3=>:three, 4=>:four, 5=>:five}

# or

h1[3] = :three
p h1.merge h2
# => {1=>:one, 2=>:two, 3=>:three, 4=>:four, 5=>:five}
```

And applied to your code:

```
h = { key: :value1, foo: :value2 }

after_key = :key
after_key_index = h.keys.index(after_key)
h1,h2 = h.partition {|k,v| h.keys.index(k) <= after_key_index }.map {|a| Hash[a]}

p h1.merge(:bar => :value3).merge(h2)
# => {:key=>:value1, :bar=>:value3, :foo=>:value2}

# or

h1[:bar] = :value3
p h1.merge h2
# => {:key=>:value1, :bar=>:value3, :foo=>:value2}
```